# Sort unsorted Array A into empty Array B

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, pseudocode

I'm sorry, but I couldn't think of a good title. I have a homework assignment that seems simple, but I couldn't get it done at all. The idea is simple:

You have an unsorted array "A" and an empty array "B". You must make B into a sorted version of A by doing the following:

- Find the smallest value of A that you didn't already insert into B.
- Insert that value into the first empty position of B.
- Repeat until B is full.

When I first heard the assignment, it seemed completely simple, but I am not being able to implement at all. It's supposed to be in pseudocode, but I tried Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] A = new int[]{3,4,2};
    int[] B = new int[A.length];

    int lastindex = -1;
    int lastchanged = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++)
    {
        int small = A[0];
        lastchanged = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            if (lastindex > -1)
            {
                if (A[i] <= small && i != lastindex && A[i] > A[lastindex])
                {
                    small = A[i];
                    lastchanged = i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                small = A[i];
                lastchanged = i;                    
            }
        }
        B[j] = small;
        lastindex = lastchanged;
    }
```

I've thought of representing empty values of B as 0s, but then I have trouble if my "A" has a zero, similar problem in using -1s.

Comment: Hints: 1) I'd figure out how to get the *first* element into B.  2) Once I did that, the last element added to B will always be the current smallest in A

Answer (score 0):

The value you use for empty placeholders in `B` shouldn't matter. You are inserting into `B` starting with index 0 and just replacing whatever value is in there, then replacing index 1, etc. So why does it matter what value in in `B` initially?  It could be any number in there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly...

```
b[0] = a[0];
```

Then the following block of code can be put into a `for` loop to iterate through every element of a[]:

```
if(a[1] < b[0]) {
    b[1] = b[0];
    b[0] = a[1];
} else {
    b[1] = a[1];
}
```

There's more to it than just this.  You need to compare a to every element in b until you get it to it's right spot... but as you said, this is homework... so I'll leave some of it up to you.